# Django ldap authentication, problem with multi-valued DN groups

Tags: django, authentication, ldap

I'm getting crazy cause of Django LDAP authentication.
I'm able to connect to the LDAP server (MS Active Directory), search for the user but unable to verify against groups (using the config param `AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP`).

Asking more detail about the AD structure, I found that the group use a multi-valued DN to store the users, named `member`

Studying the documentation, I found many `AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE` that manage that attribute, like:

- `MemberDNGroupType`
- `NestedMemberDNGroupType`
  and their subclasses, but none of it can find the user in one of two groups

A screenshot of the group `member` attribute:
[member list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VmfI.png)

This is the Django configuration related to LDAP

```
AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS ={
    ldap.OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION:ldap.VERSION3,
    ldap.OPT_REFERRALS:0
}
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = NestedActiveDirectoryGroupType()

# Baseline configuration.
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ldap://ldap.xxxx.com'

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = 'auth_user@xxxx.com'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = 'qwerty'

AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP = (
        LDAPGroupQuery('cn=group_1,ou=group_container,dc=xxxx,dc=com') |
        LDAPGroupQuery('cn=group_2,ou=group_container,dc=xxxx,dc=com'))

AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(
    'ou=user_container,dc=xxxx,dc=com',
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    '(UserPrincipalName=%(user)s)',
 )

AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(
    'ou=group_container,dc=xxxx,dc=com',
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
    '(objectClass=nestedActiveDirectoryGroup)',
 )

AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True

AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

The DN,OU,DC are correct for both users and groups.

Could be the problem related to the `member` attribute type?

Any idea on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the error.
Everything was cause by a Typo for the attribute OU in AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP.
Fixed this and changed the AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE to ActiveDirectoryGroupType everything start working.